# Why is cat running as a daemon on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-dash, services, zeitgeist

`/bin/cat` appears to be running as a persistent daemon on my 12.04 system.

```
$ ps aux | grep cat

detlef 2278 0.0 0.0 8680 352 ? S 06:13 0:00 /bin/cat
```

Why does Ubuntu 12.04 need `cat` running as a daemon? It didn't on my 10.04.4 system.

Comment: ~$ ps aux | grep cat;
detlef    2181  0.0  0.2 329872  9952 ?        Sl   06:13   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon
detlef    2278  0.0  0.0   8680   352 ?        S    06:13   0:00 /bin/cat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `cat` is running as part of the Unity Dash Text-Search service (`zeitgeist-fts`)

`cat` is *not* a daemon; conCATenate is a utility which joins one or more input files into a single output file.

- `/bin/cat` runs on Ubuntu 12.04 as a part of the [**Zeitgeist**](http://zeitgeist-project.com/experience/) service, which logs events, history, etc. and *also* enables the search-as-you-type in the dash feature.
- Specifically, it is started by `zeitgeist-fts` (Zeitgeist Full-Text-Search), which is the Zeitgeist component providing the search feature.
- Proof: notice the PID of `cat` (3082) in `ps` and`pstree` output:

  ```
  $ ps aux | grep /bin/cat
  ```

  ```
  izx       3082  0.0  0.0  11372   568 ?        S    Jun08   0:00 /bin/cat
  ```

  and

  ```
  $ pstree -p | grep zeit
  ```

  ```
  ├─zeitgeist-daemo(3051)───{zeitgeist-daemo}(3061)
      ├─zeitgeist-datah(3076)───{zeitgeist-datah}(3081)
      └─zeitgeist-fts(3075)─┬─cat(3082)
                            └─{zeitgeist-fts}(3080)
  ```
- Zeitgeist/Unity did not exist in 10.04, so no `cat` either! As for *why* it's needed, `cat` is universally used for text processing, and the function of its parent `zeitgeist-fts` is...text processing :)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining and your comprehensive help.

Comment: There is a button having the tooltip: "Click to set this answer as your accepted answer. click again to toggle." There is no feedback when I click on it in the  web service "Ask Ubuntu". It does not become green. Secondly, the tooltip has been appended this morning with the text "Accepted 6 mins ago." But I had not visited it 6 mins ago.  acid3.acidtests.org shows that JavaScript is activated with me.

Comment: @user43816 : it was accepted, I think you unaccepted it by mistake 6 minutes ago. Perhaps try logging out and logging in? Otherwise you can simply click the flag link below the answer and use the other option to inform a site moderator of this issue.

Comment: izx: I logged out. I logged in. Now I was able to color the button green. --  Thank you again for your comprehensive help.